# iOS - Shadow won't resize correctly

Tags: ios, calayer, shadow

I have a tableView with dynamic cell sizes, and having trouble resizing the shadow when the cells are being reused. This solution works on iOS8 but not on iOS7. Also the shadows show up correctly based on the cell size the first time the shadow is create, but they break after cells are being reused.

```
@implementation

    static const CGFloat shadowWithInset = 2;
    static const CGFloat shadowHeightOutset = 4;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    CALayer *layer = self.innerView.layer;

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor gray] CGColor];
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
    //layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    //layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGSize size = layer.bounds.size;
    layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(shadowWithInset, size.height-shadowHeightOutset, size.width-(shadowWithInset*2), shadowHeightOutset)].CGPath;
}

- (void)layoutSubViews {
   [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = self.innerView.bounds.size;
    layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(shadowWithInset, size.height-shadowHeightOutset, size.width-(shadowWithInset*2), shadowHeightOutset)].CGPath;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After populating all textfields in cellForRowAtIndexPath I ended up doing this:

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```